# How to know from Json which class an object is in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, web

I have the following JSON object in the body of a request:

**JSON**

```
{
    "nombre": "example",
    "number": 100,
    "listOfMeasurables":{
          "measurableOne":{
              "positionOne":[0,3,0],
              "positionTwo":[0,3,0]
          },
          "measurableTwo":{
              "positionOne":[0,3]
          }
    }
}
```

Now i have Class Measurable which is Abstract, and MeasurableOne, MeasurableTwo, and MeasurableThree, which extends Measurable.

**Measurable**

```
public abstract class Measurable {
    public abstract String getType();
    
}
```

**MeasurableOne**

```
public class MeasurableOne extends Measurable {
    protected int [] positionOne;
    protected int [] positionTwo;
    
    public MeasurableOne(int [] positionOne, int [] positionTwo) {
        this.positionOne = positionOne;
        this.positionTwo = positionTwo;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "MeasurableOne";
    }
}
```

**MeasurableTwo**

```
public class MeasurableTwo extends Measurable {
    protected int [] positionOne;
    
    public MeasurableTwo(int [] positionOne) {
        this.positionOne = positionOne;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "MeasurableTwo";
    }
}
```

**MeasurableThree**

```
public class MeasurableThree extends Measurable {
    protected int [] positionOne;
    protected int [] positionTwo;
    protected int [] positionThree;
    
    public MeasurableThree(int [] positionOne, int [] positionTwo, int [] positionThree) {
        this.positionOne = positionOne;
        this.positionTwo = positionTwo;
        this.positionThree = positionThree;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "MeasurableThree";
    }
}
```

Now, i have a controller, which will receive this json. The listOfMeasurables array, can contain either measurableOne, measurableTwo, measurableThree, 1, 2 or 3 of them, in any order. How can i make the controller know which type the measurables be in order to create that object?

```
@PostMapping(path = "/createActivity")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createActivity(@RequestBody Activity activity) { ->> HERE
        
    }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please also post your class `Activity`.

Comment: Oh its not written, just to tell there is where that json lands, it can be changed to whatever is needed

Answer (score 2):

your `Activity` can be defined with following code, the jackson will handle it

```
public class activity{
    private String nombre;
    private Integer number;
    private ListOfMeasurables listOfMeasurables;

    // getter and setter
}

public class ListOfMeasurables {
    private MeasurableOne measurableOne;
    private MeasurableTwo measurableTwo;
    private MeasurableThree measurableThree;

    // getter and setter 
}
```